# How to display checked check boxes together with non-checked ones

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, foreach

I have 5 check boxes from which a user can select one or more choices. The selected choices are then updated in database. The user's choices are then displayed/reviewed on another page. However my issue is that I want to show the updated choices together with the non-selected choices when doing a foreach loop in PHP.

These are the 5 check boxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="fishing">Fishing
<input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="camping">Camping
<input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="hiking">Hiking
<input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="swimming">Swimming
<input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="running">Running

<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Heres the code that updates

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

 $interestArr = $_POST['interest'];


$interest = new Interest();
$newArr = implode(',', $interestArr);

$interest->updateInterests($id=19, $newArr);
```

}

Heres the code that displays

```
<?php 

 $interest = new Interest();
 $interests = $interest->showInterests($userid=19)->interests;

 $newArr = explode(',', $interests);

 foreach ($newArr as $data) {

 echo '<input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="'.$data .'" checked>'.$data;
}
```

The update choices are stored under the interests column in DB like so 
fishing,camping,running

And the foreach loop displays them checked check box with the correct corresponding labels.

How can I display the other check boxes that were not selected just so that the user might want to make changes?

Thanks.

Comment: This code save all the checked checkboxes into database and not un checked one. So you have to keep records of all checkboxes either into one global array or into Database and then check against check box in foreach loop where you print check boxes. If you global check box has the same value as it's in Database keep it checked else keep it unchecked.

Comment: Thanks @Vantiya. I think I am getting your groove and it looks good. Would you mind providing some code snippets to get me started. Thanks.

Comment: is the intrest list a static array or you get it from another table ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI, its from a table in db. The same table that gets updated.

Comment: I am going to store all interest variables in another column in the same table and like what our good friend Vantiya suggested, I am going to do a comparison loop and see how we go.

Comment: check my answer , i'm just taking example on static data , so adapt your code to make it dynamic as you want .

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have an array of choice list like :

```
$choices = ["Fishing", "Camping" , "Hiking","Swimming" , "Running" ]
```

after the user select their choices

```
$interests = ["Fishing" , "Running" ];
```

In your case , the coresponding line is :

```
$interest = new Interest();
$interests = $interest->showInterests($userid=19)->interests;
$newArr = explode(',', $interests);
```

> Let's suppose that **$newArr** is equal to **$interests** in may example.

```
 foreach ($interests as $interest) {
 echo 'you have choose '.$interest.PHP_EOL;
}
```

As result :

```
you have choose Fishing
you have choose Running
```

For not selected :

```
$notInterests = array_diff($choices,$interests);

 foreach ($notInterests as $notInterest) {
 echo 'you have not choose '.$notInterest.PHP_EOL;
}
```

As Result :

```
you have not choose Camping
you have not choose Hiking
you have not choose Swimming
```

To handle it in one loop :

```
foreach ($choices as $choice) {

  if(in_array($choice,$interests )){
     echo'you have choose '.$choice.PHP_EOL ;
  }else{
      echo 'you have not choose '.$choice.PHP_EOL;
  }

}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Nicely done bro, I'll try to nest the other foreach loop ($notInterests) under the first foreach loop and echo all in one go. I might need a hand in this one still. Thanks alot. Wish I could upvote you but I am still below 15 reputation points.

Comment: in case you want to handle it in one loop , check again the answer .

Comment: Awesome, I'll run it through and get back.

Comment: You brilliant Mohammed Yassine CHABLI. Thank you so much, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example to illustrate the main idea. This code is intended to run in the single script.

The main ideas are:

- Use a *global* list of interests to drive the form.
- Keep a separate *global* list of *checked* check boxes which you can compare to determine if the checkbox should be checked.
- when the form is submitted, populate the list which keeps track of checked items
- render the form and compare the list of *available checkboxes* with *checked checkboxes*. If item found in both lists, it means that we want to display the checkbox as checked.

**index.php**

```
<?php
// Keep this outside of the if statement so the form has access to it.
$availableInterests = [
    'fishing',
    'camping',
    'hiking',
    'swimming',
    'running',
];

// Keep this outside of the if statement so the form has access to it.
$selectedInterests = [];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    // Cast the posted interests to an array in case the user submitted an empty list. 
    // An empty list would be NULL if we didn't cast it. 
    $selectedInterests = (array)$_POST['interest'];

    // foreach $selectedInterests insert into DB...

    // Let this code `fall through` to render the form again.
    // $selectedInterests is now populated and can be used in to the form below to keep the selected checkboxes checked.
}
?>

<form method="post">

    <!-- Using the `global` $availableInterests array to drive our form. -->
    <? foreach ($availableInterests as $interest): ?>

        <!-- Do we want to render the checkbox as checked? -->
        <?php $checked = (in_array($interest, $selectedInterests)) ? ' checked' : ''; ?>

        <input type="checkbox"
               name="interest[]"
               value="<?php echo $interest; ?>"
            <?php echo $checked; ?>>
        <?php echo ucfirst($interest); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To help others that might be in a similar situation I would like to post what is now a working solution at least for me based on Mohammed Yassine CHABLI's inspiration. Vantiya who was the first to comment really help me appreciate what was to follow. Thanks guys.

```
<?php

  $interest = new Interest();
  $interests = $interest->showInterests($userid=19)->interests;
  $choices = $interest->showInterests($userid=19)->choices;

  $selected = explode(',', $interests);
  $choices = explode(',', $choices);

  foreach ($choices as $choice) {

   if(in_array($choice,$selected )){
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="'.$choice .'" 
    checked>'.$choice;

    }else{
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="'.$choice .'" 
      unchecked>'.$choice;

    } 
}
```